# Display textbox on each selection in the multiselect

Tags: html, jquery, css

Need to display textbox on each selection. For example: When the user is selecting the first option(Product1(29)), a textbox need to display aside the Product 1 to enter the value. Multiple textbox need to display if more than one option is selected. The value entering in the textbox should belongs to the selected option. Note: The dropdown options texts are dynamically generating.

Thanks in advance.

```js
//loop through slctpicker option 
$(".selectpicker option").each(function(i) {
  //append textboxes for each options
  $(".textboxes").append("<div class='counts'><label>" + $(this).text() + " </label><input type=text name='product_counts' id=" + i + " placeholder='Enter counts ..'></div>")
})
//onchnage of select
$(".selectpicker").on("change", function() {
  $(".counts").hide() //hide all counts divs
  //loop through selctd options
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(); //get indx of options 0,1..etc
    $("#" + index).closest("div.counts").show() //show that divs 
  });
})
```

```css
.counts {
  display: none
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Sr No.</td><td>Requested Qty</td><td>Assign</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>12</td>
<td><select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>H No1 (29)</option>
  <option>H No2 (20)</option>
  <option>H No3 (27)</option>
</select>

<div class="textboxes">
  <!--here textboxes will come-->
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>15</td>
<td><select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>H No1 (29)</option>
  <option>H No2 (20)</option>
  <option>H No3 (27)</option>
</select>
<div class="textboxes">
  <!--here textboxes will come-->
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate textbox for each options using `each` loop and make them hidden . Then, whenever any options get selected from dropdown you just need to get `index()` of option which is selected and use `.show()` to show that particular inputs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//loop through slctpicker option 
$(".selectpicker option").each(function(i) {
  //append textboxes for each options
  $(".textboxes").append("<div class='counts'><label>" + $(this).text() + " </label><input type=text name='product_counts' id=" + i + " placeholder='Enter counts ..'></div>")
})
//onchnage of select
$(".selectpicker").on("change", function() {
  $(".counts").hide() //hide all counts divs
  //loop through selctd options
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(); //get indx of options 0,1..etc
    $("#" + index).closest("div.counts").show() //show that divs 
  });
})
```

```css
.counts {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>Product1 (29)</option>
  <option>Product2 (20)</option>
  <option>Product3 (27)</option>
</select>
<div class="textboxes">
  <!--here textboxes will come-->
</div>
```

***Update 1*** :

You can write `keyup` event on your input box .So, whenever user type any number you can get the total of all inputs and then simply compare with the requested quantity if greater show some error message.

***Demo code*** :

```js
//loop through slctpicker option 
$("tr td select.selectpicker").each(function() {
  var sr_no = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text()
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr")
  $(this).find("option").each(function(i) {
    //append textboxes for each options
    selector.find(".textboxes").append("<div class='counts' data-srno=" + sr_no + "><label>" + $(this).text() + " </label><input type=text name='product_counts'  data-id=" + i + " placeholder='Enter counts ..'></div>")

  })


})
//onchnage of select
$(".selectpicker").on("change", function() {
  var sr_no = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text(); //get row no
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr");
  selector.find(".counts:not(:visible) input").val("") //empty value
  selector.find(".counts").hide() //hide counts
  //loop through selctd options
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(); //get indx of options 0,1..etc
    selector.find("input[data-id=" + index + "]").closest("div[data-srno=" + sr_no + "]").show() //show that divs 
  });
})
//on keyup
$(document).on("keyup", ".counts input", function() {
  var total_qty = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text())
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr");
  var total = 0;
  //loop through counts div which is visible
  selector.find(".counts:visible input").each(function() {
    //sum 
    total += ($(this).val() != "") && ($(this).val() !== undefined) ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0
  })
  //compare
  if (total > total_qty) {
    alert("Current total is " + total + " Please enter less then" + total_qty)
  }


})
```

```css
.counts {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Sr No.</td>
    <td>Requested Qty</td>
    <td>Assign</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>
      <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option>H No1 (29)</option>
        <option>H No2 (20)</option>
        <option>H No3 (27)</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="textboxes">
        <!--here textboxes will come-->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>
      <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option>H No1 (29)</option>
        <option>H No2 (20)</option>
        <option>H No3 (27)</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="textboxes">
        <!--here textboxes will come-->
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Need 1 more help if possible for you. I've updated the code. The total count entering in the text boxes should not exceed the requested qty against each row.

Comment: each row will have different textboxes ? like for row 1 - there will be textboxes for selects ,then for row2 also same ?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention. Dropdown options values almost times will be different for each rows. FYI, I can pass a unique id from the DB to each dropdown options. The textboxes belongs to each options. So yes, all the textboxes are different

Comment: Example:The sum of numbers entering in the textboxes in the first row should not exceed the Requested Qty ( 12 ).

Comment: total here you mean total of each textboxes for first row = 12? or individual textboxes ?

Comment: Sum of all textboxes for first row  <= 12

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <!- // NOTE // add an id to the select statement ->
    <select id="productPicker" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
      <option>Product1 (29)</option>
      <option>Product2 (20)</option>
      <option>Product3 (27)</option>
    </select>
    <!- // NOTE // a text input to select the quantity ->
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="productCount" placeholder="Enter value here..." />
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#productPicker').on('change', function() {
        $('#productCount').css('display', 'block');
      });
  </script>
</html>
```

** Note that what you do with that productCount value was not part of your question.

Comment: HI, THanks for the reply. Multiple textbox need to display if more than one option is selected. Note: the options are dynamically generating.

Comment: @ubs0305 If you're dynamically adding options, you should also be dynamically adding the input boxes with them.  How are you creating the options? Server-side or client-side?

Comment: The dropdown option values are generated from the server side

Comment: @ubs0305 I suggest you also submit that server-side code. Can't solve a puzzle without all the pieces.

Comment: <select id="productPicker" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true"> <?php foreach ($products as $product):?>
<option><?php echo $product->product_name.'('.$product->prod_count.')'.;?></option>
<?php endforeach;?></select>

Comment: This is how I display the product names from the database.